# Is np.set_printoptions() just for display purposes?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

float_number_1 = -0.09115307778120041
float_number_2 = -0.41032475233078003
print(float_number_1)                              #-0.09115307778120041
print(float_number_2)                              #-0.41032475233078003

my_array= np.array([[float_number_1, float_number_2]], dtype=np.float64)
for number in my_array:
    print(number)                                           #[-0.09115308 -0.41032475]
```

Now when I add the following:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=50)
```

and print **my_array** again I get the full numbers:

```
[-0.09115307778120041 -0.41032475233078003]
```

Is set_printoptions  just for display purposes or does this affect the actual precision of the numbers held in the numpy array?
I need to keep the precision for calculation purposes.

Also, what is the maximum precision I can set for float64?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just there for display options. The storage format for numbers is not altered. From the [`numpy.set_printoptions()` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

> These options determine the way floating point numbers, arrays and other NumPy objects are **displayed**.

(Bold emphasis mine)

A 64-bit floating point number has [53 bits of significand precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), so the smallest binary fraction is 2^-52, or `2.220446049250313e-16`; about 16 decimal digits, so going beyond `np.set_printoptions(precision=16)` there probably is not much point.

Note that the setting for `floatmode` also matters; the default is `'maxprec_equal'`, which means that the number of digits actually shown depends on the actual values in your array; if you set `precision=16`, but your array values can be all be uniquely represented with just 4 decimals, then numpy will not use more. Only if `floatmode` is set to `'fixed'` will numpy stick to a larger precision setting.

On what it means to *uniquely* represent floating point numbers: Because floating point numbers are an *approximation* using binary fractions, there is a whole range of Real numbers that all would result in the exact same floating point representation e.g. 0.5 and 0.50000000000000005 both end up as the binary value `00111111000000000000000000000000`. Numpy strives to find the fewest number of decimal digits that a floating point number can represent, then show that to you.

Comment: So if I don't use it, there is no danger of losing precision? right?

Comment: @HarryBoy: indeed. It is *only* used when producing the string output (representation) of numpy values.